# Web API 2 return text/html response not working

Tags: f#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an older HTTP API that I need to replace with a newer one written with web api 2. I am proxying the old one through the new one while it is being built. For example, /user/1234 if implemented on the new one will be served from it, but if not found on the new one will be proxied from the old.

Now, it's working in case of most response types (application/json, text/plain, text/xml), but it doesn't return the proxied HTML responses. Here is the F# code that does this:

```
let msg = new HttpRequestMessage(x.Request.Method, x.Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery)
if x.Request.Method <> HttpMethod.Get then msg.Content <- x.Request.Content
let req = async {
    let client = new HttpClient()
    client.BaseAddress <- new Uri("http://old.api.url")
    let! response = client.SendAsync(msg) |> Async.AwaitTask
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() |> ignore
    return response
}
Async.RunSynchronously(req)
```

It just returns the HttpResponseMessage that was received from the old API. It works fine in cases of application/json and text/plain (which is what the old one returns most of the time) but even though it receives the proper HTML response (seen in the debugger) it doesn't return it. The response I receive is always from the previous request. So if I get a json response to a /foo/bar request, if I then call /foo/baz which has a text/html response, it still returns the response from /foo/bar.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could caching be the culprit?

Comment: I haven't added any caching. Also, the URI is different. A cache wouldn't return a copy from a different URI.